# C# - Calculating Final Percentage with Grievance or Discount Followed by Sale Discount

Tags: c#, .net

I'm facing an issue with calculating a final percentage that involves either a grievance or a discount, followed by applying a discount for a sale. Here's the breakdown of my problem:

Initial Setup:

There are two types of adjustments to the base price: Grievance or Discount.
The type of adjustment is determined by a string value, which can be either "GRIEVANCE" or "DISCOUNT".
Percentages:

The adjustment percentage (either for grievance or discount) from the "matriz" is always positive.
There's also a sale discount percentage which is applied after the initial adjustment.
Goal:

Calculate the final percentage adjustment considering the initial grievance/discount followed by the sale discount.
Here's my code snippet:

```
// Determine if the adjustment is a discount
bool isMatrizDiscount = matrizDescription == "DISCOUNT";

// Percentages (always positive)
int matrizPercentage = 100; // Grievance or discount from matriz
int saleDiscountPercentage = 10; // Discount from sale

// Convert percentages to decimal for calculation
double matrizPercentageDivided = matrizPercentage / 100.0;
double saleDiscountPercentageDivided = saleDiscountPercentage / 100.0;

// Calculating final percentage
var finalPercentual = isMatrizDiscount
    ? 1 - ((1 - saleDiscountPercentageDivided) * (1 - Math.Abs(matrizPercentageDivided)))
    : 1 / ((1 - saleDiscountPercentageDivided) * (1 + Math.Abs(matrizPercentageDivided))) - 1;

finalPercentual = Math.Floor(finalPercentual * 100);

// Determine the description based on final percentage
var description = finalPercentual <= 0 ? "GRIEVANCE" : "DISCOUNT";

// Expecting 80, due to a 100% grievance followed by a 10% sale discount
finalPercentual = Math.Abs(finalPercentual);
```

The issue arises when trying to calculate the `finalPercentual`. With a 100% grievance, followed by a 10% sale discount, I would expect the final percentage to be 80%. However, the calculation doesn't seem to yield the correct result.

Could anyone help clarify where I might be going wrong with this calculation?

Comment: Can you please explain how this math is intended to work?  It's hard to understand your intent here.  Why would you expect `finalPercentual` to be `80` if the `matrizDescription` is `GRIEVANCE` with these values?  I get `45` with the current logic

Comment: *// Expecting 80, due to a 100% grievance followed by a 10% sale discount* - what does that mean? If I saw something in a shop and a sign saying "100% discount, plus an extra 10% off" i'd either expect the item to be free, or the shop to pay me 10% of the marked price to take the item away. Imagine explaining this problem to someone who never worked in your industry, doesn't know anything about what you've done so far, and doesn't know what a grievance adjustment is, but does know what a discount/percentage reduction is and is reasonably smart and willing to help. That's us